# Populate DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView on `Form1`. I need to fill the Dgv with a specific method in other classes/methods, **but I can't access it**, I need help please.

The name of the DataGridView is `DataConsole`.

**Here is the method I need to use to popularize Dgv:**

```
public static void addrow(string modo, string acao, string info, int tipo_msg, string msg,
                                    string extra, int tipo_extra, string origem, string fase_origem, string metodo)
        {
            int idrow = DataConsole.Rows.Add();

            using (DataGridViewRow row = DataConsole.Rows[idrow])
            {
                row.Cells["dg_data"].Value = DateTime.Now;
                row.Cells["dg_modo"].Value = modo;
                row.Cells["dg_acao"].Value = acao;
                row.Cells["dg_info"].Value = info;

                row.Cells["dg_tipo"].Value = tipo_msg;
                row.Cells["dg_msg"].Value = msg;
                row.Cells["dg_extra"].Value = extra;
                row.Cells["dg_TipoExtra"].Value = tipo_extra;
                row.Cells["dg_origem"].Value = origem;
                row.Cells["dg_FaseOrigem"].Value = fase_origem;
                row.Cells["dg_metodo"].Value = metodo;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is the `DataConsole` accessible in this context? If not, add on more parameter to the method of DataGridView type and pass the `DataConsole` from where you call this method.

Comment: DataConsole is currently only accessible on public frm_Console ()
         {...}, I can't access it from other methods or classes.

Comment: As I guessed. So, either you do what I've suggested above OR move the DataConsole-Related codes to `frm_Console` OR assign the `DataConsole` to a global variable so you can access it anywhere in your project. I'd recommend the second option. Why would you need to have this method in a separate class? Doesn't make sense. Deal with the control within it's scope.

Comment: Even in frm_console I can't access DataConsole in the whole project, I already put his Modifiers property as public, without success, how do I define a DataGridView to be seen in the entire project? I'm starting now in C #, thanks for your patience.

Comment: No problem buddy. Please edit your question to include the relevant code to check it out with you. Because this _Even in frm_console I can't access DataConsole_ is a strange thing. We need to understand your logic. Is the `frm_Console` the container of the DGV? Do you create the DGV by the designer or by code? Do you have different namespaces in your project? Some more code to clarify please.

Comment: I create the DGV by the designer, I don't have several namespaces, I don't know what code could pass, I use this post to try to popularize the DGV, what comes before would be the method with the data to popular them addrow (....), but I cannot access the DGV from anywhere in the project, only on frm_console. If I put a loop in frm_console with the addrow (...) method to fill the DGV, it works without problems, but not in another class.

Comment: My DGV is filled in using methods during the execution of the program, it has no connection to a database, so the need for it to be accessible throughout the project

Comment: I was already public, I tried with internal, both do not work outside the frm_console class.

Comment: Yes, You need to get the opened `frm_Console` like `var frm = Application.OpenForms.Cast<frm_Console>().First();` then you can access it's internal/public objects. I'll post some alternatives.

Comment: In which part do I define this variable frm? wouldn't it have to be public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

Add a parameter for the `DataConsole` of DataGridView type in the class method and Pass it as an argument in the caller.

```cs
public static void addrow(
    DataGridView dgv,
    string modo, 
    string acao, 
    string info, 
    int tipo_msg, 
    string msg,
    string extra, 
    int tipo_extra, 
    string origem, 
    string fase_origem, 
    string metodo)
{
    var idrow = dgv.Rows.Add();
    var row = dgv.Rows[idrow];

    row.Cells["dg_data"].Value = DateTime.Now;
    row.Cells["dg_modo"].Value = modo;
    row.Cells["dg_acao"].Value = acao;
    row.Cells["dg_info"].Value = info;

    row.Cells["dg_tipo"].Value = tipo_msg;
    row.Cells["dg_msg"].Value = msg;
    row.Cells["dg_extra"].Value = extra;
    row.Cells["dg_TipoExtra"].Value = tipo_extra;
    row.Cells["dg_origem"].Value = origem;
    row.Cells["dg_FaseOrigem"].Value = fase_origem;
    row.Cells["dg_metodo"].Value = metodo;
}
```

Then you can call the method from `frm_Console` as follows:

```cs
public partial class frm_Console : Form
{
//...

    private void TheCaller()
    {
        addrow(DataConsole, //the rest of the parameters....);
    }
}
```

**Option 2**

Set the `Modifiers` property of the `DataConsole` control to Public or Internal, find it's container Form in the class method, and access it:

```cs
public static void addrow(
    string modo, 
    string acao, 
    string info, 
    int tipo_msg, 
    string msg,
    string extra, 
    int tipo_extra, 
    string origem, 
    string fase_origem, 
    string metodo)
{
    var f = Application.OpenForms.OfType<frm_Console>().FirstOrDefault();

    if (f == null) return;

    var idrow = f.DataConsole.Rows.Add();
    var row = f.DataConsole.Rows[idrow];

    row.Cells["dg_data"].Value = DateTime.Now;
    row.Cells["dg_modo"].Value = modo;
    row.Cells["dg_acao"].Value = acao;
    //...etc.
}
```

**Option 3**

Declare a static variable in the method's class of DataGridView type, set it to  `DataConsole` in `frm_Console` construcor.

```cs
public class SomeClass
{
    public static DataGridView DataConsol;

    public static void addrow(
        string modo, 
        string acao, 
        string info, 
        int tipo_msg, 
        string msg,
        string extra, 
        int tipo_extra, 
        string origem, 
        string fase_origem, 
        string metodo)
    {
        if (DataConsol == null) return; //or throw an exception...

        var idrow = DataConsol.Rows.Add();
        var row = DataConsol.Rows[idrow];

        row.Cells["dg_data"].Value = DateTime.Now;
        row.Cells["dg_modo"].Value = modo;
        row.Cells["dg_acao"].Value = acao;
        //...etc.
    }       
}

public partial class frm_Console : Form
{
    public frm_Console()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SomeClass.DataConsol = this.DataConsole;
    }
//...
}
```

**Option 4**

Keep the DataConsole-Related routines in the `frm_Console` where the control belongs.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand where I put the var f = Application.OpenForms.OfType <frm_Console> () .FirstOrDefault ();

Comment: @MaurícioMorhy See **Option 2**, Obviously in the `addrow` body.

Comment: Thank you, the 3 options worked .... Thank you very much.

Comment: @MaurícioMorhy Most welcome buddy. Have a good day.

Comment: When filling in the DGV constantly, it ends up locking the form, I can't move it because the DGV keeps updating through DataConsole.Refresh () ;, is there any way to solve this problem and I can move the form window?

Comment: @MaurícioMorhy Hello bud. Yes, make it asynchronous call. I'll check out your new post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataSource for that, its easy and more faster then adding or updating any GrdiRow to grid.
More details about DataSource can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.datasource).
Also I would suggest you to Get and set Data via DataSource itself.

Comment: DGV works as a console in my application, every 1 second it adds a line, I need to handle (sometimes even change the color of the line) the information before entering the dgv. I believe that the DataSource would not be the case.

Comment: For changing Color of Rows in DGV, you can use RowStyle or if you want to DataSource even then use ListChanged event(Which i use when ever i need to change color)

Answer (score 0):

You are having these problems, because you are not using a DataSource to populate the DataGridView (DGV). This will not only make it more difficult to show the data, but also to fetch changed data.

Every row in your DGV will be of the same type:

```
class RowData
{
    public string Modo {get; set;}
    public string Acao {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

Use Visual Studio Designer to create the DGV and a BindingSource. Let the BindingSource show types of `RowData`. This will automatically create all columns for you, which you can manually change or delete if you want.

You can also do this by hand in your code:

```
DataGridView dataConsole = new DataGridView();
DataGridViewColumn columnModo = new DataGridViewColumn(){...}
DataGridViewColumn columnAcao = new DataGridViewColumn(){...}
... // create other columns

dataConsole.Columns.Add(columnModo);
dataConsole.Columns.Add(columnAcao);
...  // add other columns
```

Now the important part:

```
// The data that will be as rows in your table:
BindingList<RowData> dataConsoleContent = new BindingList<RowData>();
```

Or if you already have some initial data:

```
List<RowData> initialData = ...
BindingList<RowData> dataConsoleContent = new BindingList<RowData>(initialData);
```

Tell the DGV that it should show the data that is in the BindingList:

```
dataConsole.DataSource = dataConsoleContent;
```

To add a new Row, simply tell dataConsoleContent object to create a new Row:

```
RowData newRow = dataConsoleContent.AddNew();

// if you have data: just fill it
newRow.Modo = ...
newRow.Acao = ...
...
```

And tell everyone who shows this BindingList that it is changed:

```
dataConsoleContent.ResetBinding().
```

If a User edits the DataGridView, adds new Rows, changes cell content, or delete rows, the result is automatically in the BindingList:

```
private void OnButtonFinishedEditing_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    IEnumerable<DataRow> allDataRows = this.dataConsoleContent;
    ProcessEditedData(allDatarows);
}
```

Using `ResetBinding` is not very efficient, because it will refresh the complete DataGridView. If you regularly will change data programmatically (so not changed by the operator), then your DataRow needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. For an example see [How to: Raise Change Notifications Using a BindingSource and the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/raise-change-notifications--bindingsource)

This is some work. Luckily there are several nuget packages where this has been done for you. One of my favorites is Nuget [Equin.ApplicationFramework.BindingListView](https://github.com/waynebloss/BindingListView). It does all the DataSource work for you, plus it has automatic sorting by clicking on the column headers. Another different feature is that it is easy to filter the shown element without removing elements from the DataSource:

```
List<Customer> customers = GetCustomers();
BindingListView<Customer> view = new BindingListView<Customer>(customers);
dataGridView1.DataSource = view;
```

In the grid you can now sort by clicking on the headers. The sort order is done automatically, as well as adjusting the "glyph" on the header which shows you the sort direction. You can programmatically sort the view using the ApplySort method.

Show only old Customers:

```
DateTime dateLimit = DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromYears(65);
view.ApplyFilter(customer => customer.Birthday < dateLimit});
```

And presto, you'll only see the elderly Customers.